# Second span going in new line

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

So I have a strange problem with Bootstrap `span`.

I have an input text with two spans. But the second `span` is going to new line.
Here is an example:

```
<div class="col-md-6" style="width:50%;margin-bottom: 10px">        
<div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Amount (to the nearest dollar)">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
</div>          
</div>
```

[JsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/al_kinkopf/fuwruczL/1/)

How to make the second span stay in the same line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the input-group-addon class to your second span.

```
<div class="col-md-6" style="width:50%;margin-bottom: 10px"> 
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Amount (to the nearest dollar)">
        <span class="input-group-addon glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

The only problem is that the glyphicon has a top:1px style which gives you an offset of 1 pixel. Just override that in your css.